# Bootstrap - Can't get "table-striped"

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using `table-stripped` with [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/).

I can target any other element with hover, everthing is good without `table-striped` but when I using `table-striped` and some elements can not be activated.

The reason this: `table-striped`

[You can see on **JSFiddle** for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/u7bqg1ks/)

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "ensure"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of CSS specificity.

Increase your CSS selector specificity value or use !important if you're lazy to override bootstrap CSS selectors.

```
table.table.table-striped tr.myTip td {
 background: red;
}
```

or

```
.myTip td {
 background: red !important;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u7bqg1ks/3/)

Comment: How can we make the faded colors of except the selected?

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the opacity of the others without selected? Only It will only be selected red color. The opacity of the others will be "0.5" Is it possible?

Comment: you can add class to your table and opaque the td which are not .myTip

Answer (score 1):

Actually your fiddle doesn't load bootstrap.css file.

`table-striped` is a bootstrap class but it is not loaded in your application so you created a css for the class `table-striped`

```
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td,
.table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

By loading the bootstrap file in the application, you just need to change the css selector by

```
.myTip > td, .myTip > th {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1ymknu4g/) link